# Same MySql DB working with a php and a python framework

Tags: php, python, mysql, django, cakephp

I have a web application that has been done using Cakephp with MySql as the DB. The webapp also exposes a set of web services that get and update data to the MySQL DB. I will like to extend the app to provide a fresh set of web services but will like to use a python based framework like web2py/django etc. Since both will be working of the same DB will it cause any problems? The reason I want to do it is because the initial app/web services was done by somebody else and now I want to extend it and am more comfortable using python/web2py that php/cakephp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has some tools to make this easier: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs

It should be fine as long as you fully understand the existing schema and what the old application was doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons to use RDBMS to provide access for different users and applications to the same data. There should absolutely no problem with this.